# Find a language $L$, such that $L \notin \mathbf{P}$, but $L^* \in \mathbf{P}$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity

I'm being asked the following

> Find a language $L$, such that $L \notin \mathbf{P}$, but $L^* \in \mathbf{P}$

For the $L \notin \mathbf{P}$-part I have to show that there is no polynomial Turing Machine that could accept $L$.

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a while, so I would appreciate any help with it.

My attempt:

Let

$$L = \{0, 1\} \cup \{0^i| M_i\text{ does not accept }\langle M_i \rangle\}$$

Then $L^* = \{0, 1\}^*$. Since this language is regular, we can defined a TM that works on the word $w$ in just a single pass $\implies$ TM runs in $O(|w|) = O(n) \implies L^* \in \mathbf{P}$.

I take this $L$ as example because it seems to me easier to show that $L \notin \mathbf{P}$ by proving that indeed there is no MT that accepts $L$ than showing that it is not accepted by any polynomial MT. To prove the former I was thinking about applying a diagolization argument on $L$.

Am I on the right track? It seems to me that I'm trying to prove something stronger than what I'm asked, so maybe there is a more straightforward way.

Thanks!

Comment: You can prove that $L$ (or a similar language) is not computable by reduction from the halting problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus when we reduce a language $A$ to a language $B$, we take an instance $x$ of A and transform it into an instance $f(x)$ of $B$ so that $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in B$.

I cannot see how $M$ halting on $w$ would mean (can be transformed such that) that $M$ doesn't accept its own description.

I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: You can make $M$ independent of its input, for example.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I on the right track? It seems to me that I'm trying to prove something stronger than what I'm asked

That looks like an excellent approach. Proving something stronger is sometimes easier<sup>1</sup> and usually useful.

What's particularly nice about your template for $L$ is that it opens up new questions about what happens if you generalise to $L = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are in different complexity classes and $B \subset A^*$. The extreme of $A$ regular and $B$ undecidable is good enough, but you could also consider $B \in NP^c$, $B \in EXP^c$, maybe specific context-free $A$, ... Perhaps it would be an interesting question to ask how *close* they can be to each other while still getting some kind of separation. If you enjoy this kind of thing, there may be a mini research project in it.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is particularly true of proofs by induction, where proving a tight bound often makes the inductive step work where a loose bound wouldn't.